# Binding IP address to domain name make Nginx server point my domain name to the default server not the one for my website contents

Tags: nginx, dns, centos, digital-ocean

I am using Nginx server to run my wordpress site on DigitalOcean.

Previously I don't have a domain name so in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

I specified `server_name` as my IP address.

Now I have bought a domain name so I thought I can bind my IP to my domain name and use it. I configured A Name and CNAME on my DNS server, in this case DO.

A Name configuration

@    my IP

=====================

CName configuration

www      @

*        @

so I updated `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file and changed the `server_name` to my domain name "mydomain.com www.mydomain.com"

However just after I thought everything is done and type my domain name on the browser it redirects me to my IP address and display another page, not the front page of my wordpress website, which works fine before. The page is the default Nginx testing page which is from /usr/share/nginx/html. I checked where this is from and find that this comes from the second server definition in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, the server block specifies a `server_name` called default_server.

I checked Nginx's manual and it says Nginx will redirect to the first server, which is the one at the line `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`. So it should be the server I defined at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Why will my domain name pass to the second server block of my Nginx configuration?

Now the most important question is, how can I access my website using my domain name?

Comment: Have you changed WordPress? Maybe WordPress is doing 301 redirect to IP address.

Comment: @RichardSmith I am not sure I am currently using a plugin called 404 to 301. I configured my ip address in the plugin. Then I changed it to my domain name it still doesn't work. Strangely now if I changed server_name back to my IP address and I type the IP address in the URL field the browser will change it to my domain name but still goes to the Nginx test page.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for showing me the hint. Now it works! After a moment of confusion tweaking my `default.conf` file, I get it working again. I just change the server_name from my IP address back to my domain name. But the previous steps really help. In the previous step I changed all the settings in wordpress that refer to my IP address, to my domain name.